# Sending Windows Messages from remote Unix terminal

Tags: windows, networking, samba

I want to use [Windows Messages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues) to turn off my monitors (using [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-syscommand), SC_MONITORPOWER). This is a popular topic among AHK threads, achieved by using `SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager`, with the two hex values mapping to WM_SYSCOMMAND and SC_MONITORPOWER.

However, I want to send the command over LAN from a Unix terminal, similar to using `net rpc shutdown` to shutdown a local Windows machine.

Is there any way to send these Windows Messages commands from Unix to Windows?